# Como deixar data atual no campo texto

Tags: html

Eu gostaria de deixar populado meu campo `text` com a `data atual`, onde a mascara que eu tenho, quando o usuário digita deixa configurado assim: `xx/xx/xxxx`. Como fazer em JS ou PHP ?

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer de duas formas, pegar a data atual do seu servidor, com PHP, ASP ou Java, ou pegar a data atual do cliente, via JS

Do servidor, com PHP:

```
<input id='data' type='text' value='<?php echo date("d/m/Y"); ?>'>
```

Do cliente, com JS:

```
function pegarDataAtual(){
   data = new Date();
   document.getElementById('data').value = data.getDay()+'/'+data.getMonth()+'/'+data.getFullYear();
}
```

Ai dentro do `onload` do body você pode chamar essa função. Simples assim :)

Recomendo a utilização no lado do servidor, é melhor confiar na data que está no seu servidor do que na data que vem do cliente

Se quiser deixar apenas na mascara, em vez de colocar no `value` do `input`, você pode colocar no atributo `placeholder`

Answer (score 1):

Essa questão pode ser resolvida neste link. Se for em Jquery claro, pois você não especificou em qual linguagem.

[Specify date format Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896776/specify-date-format-in-mask-when-using-an-input-mask)

Exemplo:

```
$('#yourInputBoxHere').mask("99/99/9999", {placeholder: 'MM/DD/YYYY' });
```

Ou em html5?

[Format Mask Date Html5](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/types/4-date.html)

Exemplo:

```
<input type=date step=7 min=2014-09-08>
<input type=time min=9:00 max=17:00 step=900>
<input type=week step=2 min=2014-W30>
```

Comment: Oi Fernando. Você poderia incluir exemplos dos links citados? Respostas que dependem de link ficam melhores como comentários (que você precisa de mais pontos para poder fazer), pois o link pode sair do ar e a resposta ficar sem sentido. Obrigado.